# Confidential transaction shows amounts

Tags: ringct, transaction-data, confidential-transactions

My understanding is that confidential transactions "hide" the amount exchanged.

However I have found [a confidential transaction](http://moneroblocks.info/tx/49ccba4fb0ab9f6f56744e8deb70c738f56bee05834c77075418215ced52f021) where the input amount is visible.

Is that expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input comes from a non-RingCT transaction.  The outputs *are* RingCT outputs, and are therefore reflected as 0.

Comment: It should also be noted that once the inputs are from RingCT transactions, even the input amounts will not be shown.